# Why does $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x!}{x^x}=0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

I'm in calc 2 and we're doing series right now. I was using the alternating series test and ran into this: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x!}{x^x}$$
I don't understand how the limit is $0$. The numerator would end up larger than the denominator, but why does that make the limit $0$? Is it that the numerator approaching infinity is so large that the denominator might as well be $0$? But you can't divide by $0$ so I don't get it. Maybe I'm missing a super basic limit law right now...

Comment: Do you intend $x$ to be natural number? Or does $x!$ mean $\Gamma(x+1)?$

Comment: You can prove the limit to be 0 by solving( in which apply log then apply sterling's approx. if you know what that is which will give you the limit to be zero)

Comment: But instead the denominator ends up "larger" than the numerator, so the whole fraction tends to $0$.

Comment: The denominator grows much faster than the numerator: $x!\sim\frac{x^x}{e^x}$

Comment: You said “the numerator would end up larger than the denominator”.  Is that what you meant to say?  Even for $x=3$ the denominator is already much larger than the numerator.

Answer (score 5):

From  $\displaystyle 0\leq \frac{x!}{x^x}=\frac{x}{x}\cdot \frac{(x-1)}{x}\cdot \frac{(x-2)}{x}\cdots\frac{1}{x}<1\cdot 1\cdot \cdots \frac{1}{x}. $

Now applying limit $x\rightarrow \infty$ and using Squeeze theorem , We get $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x!}{x^x}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Solving the limit:
$$ L =\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!}{x^{x}}$$
apply logarithm both sides
$$ \ln L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln {x!} - x\ln {x}$$
By Stirling's approx. when $x \to \infty$
$$\ln {x!} = x\ln {x} -x$$
So therefore,
$$ \ln L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \ x\ln {x} -x - x\ln {x}$$
$$ \ln L=\lim_{x \to \infty} -x$$
$$ L = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}$$
$$ L = 0$$

Edit1: Solving it without Stirling's approx.(I changed the variables so it is easy for me to write the answer)
$$ \ln L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln {n!} - n\ln {n}$$
After this we can write it as a limit of a sum
$$ \ln L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln {k!}\right) - n\ln {n}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln {k!} \approx \int_{1}^{n} \ln {x}dx = n\ln {n} - n + 1$$
The above statement is only true when $n \to \infty$
Now the limit becomes
$$ \ln L=\lim_{n \to \infty} n\ln {n} - n + 1 - n\ln {n}$$
$$ \ln L=\lim_{n \to \infty} -n+1$$
$$ L = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{-n+1}$$
$$ L = 0$$

Comment: This can also be proved without sterling's approx. by converting the limit to a limit of sum

Comment: I haven't learned sterling's approx. so I was wondering if there is just some limit rule that says anything about having a factorial in the numerator? Or any general limit rule regarding factorials?

Comment: I will make an edit to my answer and solve it without sterling's approx.

Comment: It's Stirling not sterling. Sterling is the British currency.

Comment: How comes that you have $k!$ in the series ? And not $k$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Think of $x$ balls.

1. The # of arrangements of $x$ balls $x$ at a time when repetition is not allowed = $^xP_x = x!$
2. The # of arrangements of $x$ balls $x$ at a time when repetition is allowed = $x^x$

Which is bigger?

---

$x! = x(x - 1)(x - 2) ... 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$

$x - k < x$ where $k$ is any number and so if $x^p = x - 1, p < 1 \implies p = 1 - d$

So, $x! = x^1 \times x^{1 - d_1} \times x^{1 - d_2} \times .... \times x^{1 - d_{x - 1}}$

$x! = x^{x - (d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_{x - 1})}$

Let $d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_{x - 1} = s$

So, $\frac{x!}{x^x} = \frac{x^{x - s}}{x^x} = \frac{1}{x^s}$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!}{x^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^s} = 0$

Comment: But how much bigger? How do you complete this argument to conclude said limit is zero? $n+100$ is also "bigger" than $n$, yet their ratio does not tend to zero.

Comment: If we express $x!$ as a power of $x$ then $x! = x^n$ but $x^n < x^x$. So $\frac{x!}{x^x} = x^{n - x} = \frac{1}{x^m}$ Then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x!}{x^x} = \lim_{x \to  \infty} \frac{1}{x^m} = 0$

Answer (score 1):

A proof using only rational numbers (I assume that $x\in\Bbb Z_+$):

For $x\ge 6$ (for example), let $k$ be the floor of $x/2$. Then
$$\frac{x!}{x^x}\le 
\underbrace{\frac{x/2}x\cdot\frac{x/2}x\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{x/2}x}_{k\text{ times}}\cdot
\underbrace{\frac xx\cdot\frac xx\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac xx}_{x-k \text{ times}}
 = \left(\frac12\right)^k\le\left(\frac{25}{49}\right)^k\le\left(\frac {5}{7}\right)^x$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^n}$. Then

$$\ln a_n=\ln n!-n\ln n=\sum_{j=1}^n(\ln j-\ln n)=\sum_{j=1}^n\ln\frac{j}{n}\leq \ln\frac{1}{n}\to-\infty$$

as $n\to\infty$, where the inequality comes from the fact that $\ln\frac{j}{n}\leq0$ for all $j\in\{2,\dots,n\}$. As $e^x\to0$ as $x\to-\infty$, it follows that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Note that we we don't take $n$ to be a natural number, but instead a positive real, the result follows from this, as the function $x\mapsto\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x^x}$ is decreasing for sufficiently large $x$.